Kibana server is not ready yet and Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes
Hi here I want to run Elastic and Kibana by docker compose but when it runs I get:
Kibana server is not ready yet.

Here is my docker ps -a
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                            NAMES
c19bf038aae9   focker.ir/kibana/kibana:8.13.4                 "/bin/tini -- /usr/l…"   12 minutes ago   Up 12 minutes   0.0.0.0:5601->5601/tcp                           kibana-elk
ab6f430d9049   focker.ir/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.13.4   "/bin/tini -- /usr/l…"   52 minutes ago   Up 52 minutes   0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9300->9300/tcp   ELK_LG


My elasticsearch configuration:
version: '3.7'

services:
  elasticsearch-elk:
    image: focker.ir/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.13.4
    container_name: ${NODE_NAME}
    restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: ${NODE_NAME}
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 131072
        hard: 131072
      nproc: 8192
      fsize: -1
    networks:
      - elk-network
    ports:
      - 9200:9200/tcp
      - 9300:9300/tcp
    volumes:
      - $PWD/var/lib/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - $PWD/etc/certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: '-Xms12g -Xmx12g'
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: ${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      cluster.name: single-node-cluster
      node.name: elasticsearch-elk
      bootstrap.memory_lock: 'true'
      network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
      network.publish_host: 172.31.0.74
      http.port: 9200
      discovery.type: single-node
      indices.query.bool.max_clause_count: 8192
      search.max_buckets: 250000
      action.destructive_requires_name: 'true'
      xpack.security.http.ssl.key: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates/node.key
      xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates/node.pem
      xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates/root-ca.pem
      xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode: 'none'
      xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: 'true'
      xpack.security.transport.ssl.key: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates/node.key
      xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates/node.pem
      xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certificates/root-ca.pem
      xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: 'none'
      xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: 'true'
      xpack.security.enabled: 'true'
      xpack.security.audit.enabled: 'false'

networks:
  elk-network:
    external: true

My docker compose for kibana:
version: '3.7'

services:
  kibana:
    image: focker.ir/kibana/kibana:8.13.4
    container_name: kibana-elk
    restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: KIB_NODE_ELK
    networks:
      - elk-network
    ports:
      - 5601:5601/tcp
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: 'KIB_NODE_ELK'
      SERVER_HOST: '0.0.0.0'
      SERVER_PORT: 5601
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: 'https://172.22.0.2:9200'
      ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME: 'kibana_system'
      ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD: 'oxe2NqMmH3nNTL'
      ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_VERIFICATIONMODE: 'none'
      ELASTICSEARCH_REQUESTTIMEOUT: 180000
      ELASTICSEARCH_SHARDTIMEOUT: 180000
      XPACK_ENCRYPTEDSAVEDOBJECTS_ENCRYPTIONKEY: 'oM9K5fl3nbvW0eHG9M6V9xpzMq4DpIUk'
      XPACK_SECURITY_ENCRYPTIONKEY: 'a3V9op6LF0Rbpl8VZlPr0sJtiWp2NvcH'
      XPACK_REPORTING_ENCRYPTIONKEY: '8lfPqWmTYnRmVs0J1u7iLxGVnx1nTmDr'
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "200k"
        max-file: "10"
networks:
  elk-network:
    external: true

and also here is docker network inspect
[
    {
        "Name": "elk-network",
        "Id": "59102b6438e42a7cdb7370bf32ab31d9c684ddc37af9e6a305b6a8503fcebc9c",
        "Created": "2024-05-15T10:17:33.212808194+03:30",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.22.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.22.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "ab6f430d9049283a02409acd2abf41553e571f5a973ed6c7c6138da31bf3645e": {
                "Name": "ELK_LG",
                "EndpointID": "3b60af61d274fa56a9706c37fb80b49cc614c2a46ac89858e79b67ca1a1a750d",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:16:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.22.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c19bf038aae98277c9a6d605e8e7cbf09885288689ccafbec74088ac9a3ca9e6": {
                "Name": "kibana-elk",
                "EndpointID": "7da0a0cdfb6ba629b0e2e22515e81e8b90f849f99fed25f0f878ee2a17c36a50",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:16:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.22.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]

and my .env file that is not production:
ELASTIC_USER=elastic
ELASTIC_PASSWORD=oxe2NqMmH3nNTL
NODE_NAME=ELK_LG

and finaly here is my log for kibana container:

docker logs -f kibana-elk
Kibana is currently running with legacy OpenSSL providers enabled! For details and instructions on how to disable see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/8.13/production.html#openssl-legacy-provider
{"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2024-05-15T09:21:52.836Z","log.logger":"elastic-apm-node","ecs.version":"8.10.0","agentVersion":"4.4.0","env":{"pid":7,"proctitle":"/usr/share/kibana/bin/../node/bin/node","os":"linux 5.15.0-105-generic","arch":"x64","host":"KIB_NODE_ELK","timezone":"UTC+00","runtime":"Node.js v20.12.2"},"config":{"active":{"source":"start","value":true},"breakdownMetrics":{"source":"start","value":false},"captureBody":{"source":"start","value":"off","commonName":"capture_body"},"captureHeaders":{"source":"start","value":false},"centralConfig":{"source":"start","value":false},"contextPropagationOnly":{"source":"start","value":true},"environment":{"source":"start","value":"production"},"globalLabels":{"source":"start","value":[["git_rev","f5dc24d1969f80e4aa3ced7cc375dd00554f8c0c"]],"sourceValue":{"git_rev":"f5dc24d1969f80e4aa3ced7cc375dd00554f8c0c"}},"logLevel":{"source":"default","value":"info","commonName":"log_level"},"metricsInterval":{"source":"start","value":120,"sourceValue":"120s"},"serverUrl":{"source":"start","value":"https://kibana-cloud-apm.apm.us-east-1.aws.found.io/","commonName":"server_url"},"transactionSampleRate":{"source":"start","value":0.1,"commonName":"transaction_sample_rate"},"captureSpanStackTraces":{"source":"start","sourceValue":false},"secretToken":{"source":"start","value":"[REDACTED]","commonName":"secret_token"},"serviceName":{"source":"start","value":"kibana","commonName":"service_name"},"serviceVersion":{"source":"start","value":"8.13.4","commonName":"service_version"}},"activationMethod":"require","message":"Elastic APM Node.js Agent v4.4.0"}
Native global console methods have been overridden in production environment.
[2024-05-15T09:21:55.363+00:00][INFO ][root] Kibana is starting
[2024-05-15T09:21:55.448+00:00][INFO ][node] Kibana process configured with roles: [background_tasks, ui]
[2024-05-15T09:22:06.687+00:00][INFO ][plugins-service] The following plugins are disabled: "cloudChat,cloudExperiments,cloudFullStory,profilingDataAccess,profiling,securitySolutionServerless,serverless,serverlessObservability,serverlessSearch".
[2024-05-15T09:22:06.793+00:00][INFO ][http.server.Preboot] http server running at http://0.0.0.0:5601
[2024-05-15T09:22:06.993+00:00][INFO ][plugins-system.preboot] Setting up [1] plugins: [interactiveSetup]
[2024-05-15T09:22:07.080+00:00][WARN ][config.deprecation] The default mechanism for Reporting privileges will work differently in future versions, which will affect the behavior of this cluster. Set "xpack.reporting.roles.enabled" to "false" to adopt the future behavior before upgrading.
[2024-05-15T09:22:11.606+00:00][INFO ][plugins-system.standard] Setting up [149] plugins: [devTools,translations,share,screenshotMode,usageCollection,telemetryCollectionManager,telemetryCollectionXpack,taskManager,kibanaUsageCollection,cloud,newsfeed,savedObjectsFinder,noDataPage,monitoringCollection,licensing,mapsEms,globalSearch,globalSearchProviders,features,guidedOnboarding,banners,licenseApiGuard,customBranding,ftrApis,fieldFormats,expressions,screenshotting,esUiShared,customIntegrations,contentManagement,dataViews,home,searchprofiler,painlessLab,management,spaces,security,telemetry,licenseManagement,snapshotRestore,lists,files,encryptedSavedObjects,eventLog,actions,notifications,cloudDataMigration,advancedSettings,grokdebugger,console,bfetch,data,savedObjectsTagging,savedObjectsManagement,unifiedSearch,graph,alerting,embeddable,uiActionsEnhanced,savedSearch,presentationUtil,expressionShape,expressionRevealImage,expressionRepeatImage,expressionMetric,expressionImage,controls,fileUpload,ingestPipelines,ecsDataQualityDashboard,dataViewFieldEditor,dataViewManagement,charts,watcher,visualizations,visTypeXy,visTypeVislib,visTypeVega,visTypeTimeseries,visTypeTimelion,visTypeTagcloud,visTypeTable,visTypeMetric,visTypeMarkdown,visTypeHeatmap,inputControlVis,expressionTagcloud,expressionPartitionVis,visTypePie,expressionMetricVis,expressionLegacyMetricVis,expressionHeatmap,expressionGauge,visTypeGauge,eventAnnotation,expressionXY,dashboard,lens,triggersActionsUi,transform,stackConnectors,stackAlerts,ruleRegistry,cases,timelines,sessionView,kubernetesSecurity,threatIntelligence,metricsDataAccess,aiops,links,discover,reporting,canvas,fleet,osquery,logsExplorer,indexManagement,rollup,remoteClusters,crossClusterReplication,indexLifecycleManagement,datasetQuality,cloudSecurityPosture,cloudDefend,discoverEnhanced,maps,dataVisualizer,ml,observabilityAIAssistant,logsShared,observabilityLogsExplorer,enterpriseSearch,observability,uptime,synthetics,observabilityOnboarding,elasticAssistant,securitySolution,securitySolutionEss,dashboardEnhanced,apmDataAccess,infra,upgradeAssistant,monitoring,logstash,assetManager,apm,ux]
[2024-05-15T09:22:11.900+00:00][INFO ][plugins.taskManager] TaskManager is identified by the Kibana UUID: e45dd955-125c-450e-8fcb-2ae4a1b863fd
[2024-05-15T09:22:12.416+00:00][INFO ][custom-branding-service] CustomBrandingService registering plugin: customBranding
[2024-05-15T09:22:13.222+00:00][WARN ][plugins.screenshotting.config] Chromium sandbox provides an additional layer of protection, but is not supported for Linux Ubuntu 20.04 OS. Automatically setting 'xpack.screenshotting.browser.chromium.disableSandbox: true'.
[2024-05-15T09:22:13.713+00:00][WARN ][plugins.security.config] Session cookies will be transmitted over insecure connections. This is not recommended.
[2024-05-15T09:22:13.754+00:00][WARN ][plugins.security.config] Session cookies will be transmitted over insecure connections. This is not recommended.
[2024-05-15T09:22:13.990+00:00][INFO ][plugins.encryptedSavedObjects] Hashed 'xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey' for this instance: +rW6aIzGO0BucOtdK6SaIjrcIqw3Lr+VwtL7U3j3C68=
[2024-05-15T09:22:14.199+00:00][INFO ][plugins.notifications] Email Service Error: Email connector not specified.
[2024-05-15T09:22:14.551+00:00][INFO ][plugins.alerting] using indexes and aliases for persisting alerts
[2024-05-15T09:22:17.617+00:00][INFO ][plugins.cloudSecurityPosture] Registered task successfully [Task: cloud_security_posture-stats_task]
[2024-05-15T09:22:21.650+00:00][INFO ][plugins.securitySolution.endpoint:user-artifact-packager:1.0.0] Registering endpoint:user-artifact-packager task with timeout of [20m], interval of [60s] and policy update batch size of [25]
[2024-05-15T09:22:22.262+00:00][INFO ][plugins.assetManager] Server is NOT enabled
[2024-05-15T09:22:22.885+00:00][ERROR][elasticsearch-service] Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. security_exception
        Root causes:
                security_exception: unable to authenticate user [kibana_system] for REST request [/_nodes?filter_path=nodes.*.version%2Cnodes.*.http.publish_address%2Cnodes.*.ip]
[2024-05-15T09:22:23.818+00:00][INFO ][plugins.screenshotting.chromium] Browser executable: /usr/share/kibana/node_modules/@kbn/screenshotting-plugin/chromium/headless_shell-linux_x64/headless_shell


Can you solve my problem?I realy need your help!

Not sure if it's the root cause but there is a typo focker.ir/kibana/kibana:8.13.4 must be docker.ir/kibana/kibana:8.13.4 and also docker.ir/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.13.4

If the problem is not above reset kibana_system user password and restart the kibana
docker exec -it ELK_LG /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -u kibana_system -i oxe2NqMmH3nNTL

@MusabDogan my image name is ok!i get them from my local repository!

Is your elasticsearch is accessible from curl?

yes elastic is accessible!
@AshishTiwari

This is a certificate issue. If you create single node cluster in docker, elasticsearch comes up with certificate authority (ca). It is needed for Kibana, Elasticsearch and other beats to communicate with each other.

Certificates and keys are generated for the transport and HTTP layers.
The Transport Layer Security (TLS) configuration settings are written to elasticsearch.yml.
A password is generated for the elastic user.
An enrollment token is generated for Kibana.

If you want to create multi node cluster please follow these instructions here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/docker.html
The script in command section creates .crt and .key certificates out of .ca which you need to use in your docker compose.
